# Ray optics approximation

Tags: optics

In the ray optics approximation,for light to be considered to be moving in a straight line path,we assume that the size of an obstacle must be very much larger than the wavelength of light.

Why do we compare the size of object only with wavelength ? Why don't we compare it with amplitude or any other property of light ?

Answer (score 1):

In ray-tracing we obtain approximate solutions to [Maxwell's equations](http://www.maxwells-equations.com/) that are valid as long as the light waves propagate through and around objects whose dimensions are much greater than the light's wavelength.

> What if the wavelength is comparable to the object's dimension?

**If the wavelength of light is comparable with the object dimension, then [diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction) could happen, which cannot be explained using ray optics**, but require [wave theory of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light#Wave_theory). Geometrical optics does not account for optical effects such as diffraction and interference.

> Why don't we compare it with amplitude or any other property of light?

Amplitude of a wave only gives you information about the intensity of light. Frequency of light is independent of the medium of propagation. For a straight line path through a homogeneous medium (one of the basic assumptions in geometric optics), the light should not suffer any bending around an obstacle (which is the phenomenon of diffraction), which is determined by it's wavelength.

Comment: ji,can you please tell me why the size of an obstacle around which light is undergoing diffraction must have dimensions much comparable to wavelength of light.You have said in your answer that "as long as light travels around obstacle of larger dimensions than wavelength of light maxwells equations are valid",does this mean maxwells equations are not valid in case of diffraction..please,explain these

Comment: No. Maxwell's equations are consistent with diffraction. What I meant is that the ray optic technique is based on certain assumptions that could only give you approximate solutions to Maxwell's equations. These assumptions fail to explain diffraction or interference, for that you require wave theory.

Comment: The cause of diffraction is that, when light passes through a very thin hole, that hole acts like a source of light of that particular wavelength. For that the hole dimension should be comparable to the light wavelength. Otherwise there will be no effect of the hole on light. Its goes like as if it is coming from the source. For a detailed discussion see http://www.everythingmaths.co.za/science/grade-11/06-2d-and-3d-wavefronts/06-2d-and-3d-wavefronts-05.cnxmlplus

Comment: For derivations on that, see these links: http://courses.washington.edu/me557/sensor/day1a.pdf. Sorry that these are somewhat a little complicated. Your question is essentially why ray optic tracing require the dimension of the obstacle to be comparable with that of light. The answer is simply the ray optic technique is just an approximation method do not give you exact solutions to Maxwell's equations. They are not meant to give explanations on interference or diffraction. You may also google Huygens principle.